# Session for user in JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp, session

I'm a beginner in Web Designing. I have an application which requires login. After i login on every next page i want to use the user's username for storing and retrieving data from mysql database. How to do this? Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

First: You have to learn about JAAS:
really complete and technical http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/AcnOnly.html

In fact it depends of your application server and the login module you want to use for login (tomcat; glassfish; kerberos; database ...)

Second: Think also to reuse cloud authentication like OpenID Connect and provider like Google, Yahoo!

Third: At the end you will found information in the Principal see [What is the meaning of Subject vs. User vs. Principal in a Security Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989063/what-is-the-meaning-of-subject-vs-user-vs-principal-in-a-security-context)