# What's the "principal" in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm really new to Spring and Spring Security. I was reading about Spring Security and it came out the concept of *principal*, which should be the current logged user. But what if we have more than one current logged user? So, my question is, what exactly is then the principal in spring security?

I've read for example this tutorial:

> http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-security/

and they seem to take into account that there's just one current logged user, which isn't often the case.

How do I retrieve a specific user? And how do I differentiate between users that are doing requests?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4989063/3924118.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The principal *is* the currently logged in user. However, you retrieve it through the security context which is bound to the current thread and as such, it's also bound to the current request and its session.

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` internally obtains the current `SecurityContext` implementation through a `ThreadLocal` variable. As a request is bound to a single thread this will get you the context of the *current request*.

To simplify you could say that the security context is in the session and contains user/principal and roles/authorities.

> How do I retrieve a specific user?

You don't. All APIs are designed to allow access to the user & session of the *current request*.

Let user A be one of 100 currently authenticated users. If A issues a request against your server, the server will allocate one thread to process that request. If you then do `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` you do so in the context of this thread. From within that thread you don't have access to the context of user B which is processed by a different thread.

> And how do I differentiate between users that are doing requests?

You don't have to, that's what the Servlet container does for you.

Comment: So, my consequent question is: how does spring differentiate between sessions, and users? I guess this requires a deeper understanding of Spring...

Comment: Thanks! Nice answer. I have just one doubt which comes from my reduced experience in creating web applications, etc. But before let me try to explain what I think I know. From what I've learnt, HTTP requests can be enhanced with a session IDs. This information is probably used by Tomcat (or whatever) to differentiate between users and requests. Principal is the current logged in user for the current context. To understand that there's a logged in user (a principal), a session number must probably be associated with it.

Comment: Now, suppose that I've two logged in users called `root` and `admin` and I've a controller whose request mapping is `/users/{username}`.
Suppose further that `root` is playing with his account on the client side at the URL `www.host.com:3000/users/root`. 
At this point, I guess a session ID has already been generated for root. If it now tries to do a request to `www.host.com:3000/users/admin`,
by changing for example the URL manually, and admin is also connected and logged in from another machine, what would happen in this case?

Comment: I guess this would not be allowed by the server because the request does probably not contain the right information, i.e. the right session id?

Comment: @nbro With RestController just need to add the Principal arg [like here](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/trunk/app/src/main/java/org/apache/roller/weblogger/ui/restapi/UserController.java#L95), Spring will automatically populate it, and you can do whatever security checking desired.  (e.g., if P is "root" but is trying to see "admins" page throw a 403 error but allow it he's trying to his page.)  See Section 15.3.2.3 [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html) for all the arguments you can choose that Spring will populate for you automatically.

Comment: @GlenMazza github link you shared is broken

Answer (score 7):

**Brief definition of Principal:**

A **Principal** represents a user's identity.

It can be a String object having username on a simple level or a complex **UserDetails** object.

Answer (score 5):

Principal is just an old interface from **Java SE 6**.

As all interfaces without default implementation **it simple** **defines some methods** **which are required to be implemented by the class which will implement that interface**.

Those methods are

```
boolean  equals(Object another)
          Compares this principal to the specified object.

String   getName()
          Returns the name of this principal.

int      hashCode()
          Returns a hashcode for this principal.

String   toString()
          Returns a string representation of this principal.
```

As the [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html?is-external=true) states :

> This interface represents the abstract notion of a principal, **which
> can be used to represent any entity, such as an individual, a
> corporation, and a login id**.

In simple terms it is just used so that the implementer will have to implement this interface in a way that he makes an entity uniquely distingueed between other entities. Also the `getName()` will have to return a value by which one specific entity is uniquely identified and does not collide with other entities.
So if the `Principal` which is used is of type `UserDetails` then the `getName()` of `Principal` returns the `UserName` of `UserDetails`.

If we see the implementation that Spring uses for `AbstractAuthenticationToken.class` :

```
public String getName() {
        if (this.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
            return ((UserDetails)this.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        } else if (this.getPrincipal() instanceof AuthenticatedPrincipal) {
            return ((AuthenticatedPrincipal)this.getPrincipal()).getName();
        } else if (this.getPrincipal() instanceof Principal) {
            return ((Principal)this.getPrincipal()).getName();
        } else {
            return this.getPrincipal() == null ? "" : this.getPrincipal().toString();
        }
    }
```

Also is important to mention:

`abstract class AbstractAuthenticationToken implements Authentication` and

`interface Authentication extends Principal`

`Principal` Interface also ensures that the implementer will implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` which makes much sense because the entity of Principal that represents an Organization or a Company or a Person must have some way of being compared with other entities.