# Unit testing methods using Principal from Spring Secucrity

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-security, mockito

Could someone tell me how should I test those two methods:

```
public boolean deleteUser(Principal principal) {
    if (findLoggedInUser(principal) != null) {
        userRepository.delete(findLoggedInUser(principal));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public User findLoggedInUser(Principal principal) {
    return findUserbyUsername(principal.getName());
}
```

The problem is that I'm using currently logged in user with basic authentication and don't know how, and if I can mock those Principals. Is there a way to do that? Those methods are in my Service layer so maybe I can't do unit tests and I'm left with integration tests because those methods heavily use DB?

EDIT 1:
**My changed test class:**

```
public class UserServiceBeanTest {

@Spy
@InjectMocks
private UserServiceBean userServiceBean;

@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Mock
private Principal principal;

@Mock
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Mock
private User userStub;

private String defaultName = "user";
private  String defaultPassword = "password";
private String defaultEmail = "example@example.com";

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}


@Test
public void shouldReturnTrue_whenUserDeleted() {
    //given
    when(principal.getName()).thenReturn(defaultName);
    when(userServiceBean.findLoggedInUser(principal)).thenReturn(userStub);

    // when
    boolean removed = userServiceBean.deleteUser(principal);

    //then
    assertTrue(removed);
    verify(userRepository, times(1));
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnFalse_whenUserNotFound() {
    //given
    when(principal.getName()).thenReturn(defaultName);
    when(userServiceBean.findLoggedInUser(principal)).thenReturn(null);

    //when
    boolean removed = userServiceBean.deleteUser(principal);

    //then
    assertFalse(removed);
    verify(userRepository, times(0));
}

}
```

I'm getting those errors now:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException:
```

Missin

```
g method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at com.doublemc.services.UserServiceBeanTest.shouldReturnTrue_whenUserDeleted(UserServiceBeanTest.java:63)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.


    at com.doublemc.services.UserServiceBeanTest.init(UserServiceBeanTest.java:48)
```

EDIT 2:
**Here is my UserServiceBean class:**

```
package com.doublemc.services;

import com.doublemc.domain.ToDoItem;
import com.doublemc.domain.User;
import com.doublemc.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.security.Principal;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceBean {

private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
UserServiceBean(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}

public User saveUser(User user) {
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    newUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    newUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    return userRepository.save(newUser);
}

public boolean userExists(User user) {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null;
}

public Iterable<ToDoItem> getAllToDoItems(User user) {
    return user.getToDoItems();
}

public boolean deleteUser(Principal principal) {
    if (findLoggedInUser(principal) != null) {
        userRepository.delete(findLoggedInUser(principal));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public User findLoggedInUser(Principal principal) {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(principal.getName());
}
```

}

**Here is my UserRepository:**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

EDIT 6: I created myself three more tests:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnUser_whenPassedUser() {
    // given
    when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(new User(defaultName, defaultPassword, defaultEmail));

    // when
    User savedUser = userServiceBean.saveUser(userStub);

    // then
    assertNotNull(savedUser);
    verify(userRepository, times(1)).save(any(User.class));
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnTrue_whenUserExists() {
    // given
    when(userStub.getUsername()).thenReturn(defaultName);
    when(userRepository.findByUsername(userStub.getUsername())).thenReturn(userStub);

    // when
    boolean exists = userServiceBean.userExists(userStub);

    // then
    assertTrue(exists);
    verify(userRepository, times(1)).findByUsername(defaultName);
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnFalse_whenUserNotFoundByUsername() {
    // given
    when(userStub.getUsername()).thenReturn(defaultName);
    when(userRepository.findByUsername(userStub.getUsername())).thenReturn(null);

    // when
    boolean exists = userServiceBean.userExists(userStub);

    // then
    assertFalse(exists);
    verify(userRepository, times(1)).findByUsername(defaultName);
}
```

And here are tested methods:
**UserServiceBean.saveUser**:

```
public User saveUser(User user) {
    User newUser = new User(user.getUsername(), user.getEmail(), passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    return userRepository.save(newUser);
}
```

**UserServiceBean.userExists**:

```
public boolean userExists(User user) {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null;
}
```

Comment: Test what about them?

Comment: Well, if for example deleteUser method actually deletes a user - that's what tests are for, right?

Comment: No, you shouldn't test that `deleteUser` actually deletes a user: you should check that it invoked `userRepository.delete` with the parameter you expect. Whether that actually deletes a user is up to the implementation of `userRepository`.

Comment: So if I have already tested repositories then I don't have to test any other methods in my Service layer which communicate controllers and repos?

Comment: What is `Principal`? There are several types named that.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's currently logged in user in Spring Securty. Here is more about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499307/whats-the-principal-in-spring-security

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how i would do it (**Junit + Mockito**).

There are two tests cases in the given example.

Btw.. i think you could do a little refactoring as you are (i guess) hitting the database twice:

```
public boolean deleteUser(Principal principal) {
    User loggedUser = findLoggedInUser(principal);
    if (loggedUser != null) {
        userRepository.delete(loggedUser);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To the tests..

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import mypkg.Service;
import mypkg.User;
import mypkg.UserRepository;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.Spy;

import java.security.Principal;

public class ServiceTest {

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mock
    private Principal principal;

    @Mock
    private User userStub;

    private String defaultName = "name";

    @Before
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

   @org.junit.Test
   public void shouldReturnTrue_whenUserDeleted() throws Exception{
       // Arrange
       when(principal.getName()).thenReturn(defaultName);
       when(service.findUserbyUsername(defaultName)).thenReturn(userStub);

       // Act
       boolean removed = service.deleteUser(principal);

       // Assert
       Assert.assertTrue(removed);
       verify(userRepository, times(1)).delete(userStub);
   }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void shouldReturnFalse_whenUserNotFound() throws Exception{
        // Arrange
        when(principal.getName()).thenReturn(defaultName);
        when(service.findUserbyUsername(defaultName)).thenReturn(null);

        // Act
        boolean removed = service.deleteUser(principal);

        // Assert
        Assert.assertFalse(removed);
        verify(userRepository, times(0)).delete(userStub);
    }
}
```

The biggest thing to get out of this is that you Mock / Stub any outside dependencies (UserRepository in this case) and focus only on the logic contained in that service method. What is going inside that `delete` is not relevant to the test.. all you care about is whether that method has been invoked with a certain parameter.. and thats it.

Let me know if all is clear.. i will explain if needed.

**Update**

**@InjectMocks** is a convenient method of injecting dependencies into the class that you are going to test. The injection happens by setter/constructor or as a last resort by reflection.

In the above example as the `Service` class has the `UserRepository` dependency and there is a @Mock defined:

```
@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

Mockito will inject that into the `Service`.

**@Spy** is like `@Mock`, except that it allows you to selectively mock only certain bahvior and by default the real implementation is invoked.

In my case i used it to mock the `findUserbyUsername` method of the `Service` as what is going inside is not important in our two tests:

```
when(service.findUserbyUsername(defaultName)).thenReturn(userStub);
```

Comment: So I should use this kind of test (using mockito I mean) for all of my Service/Controller methods? So I don't actually use DB just mocks of repositories?

Comment: Yes. If you actually want to include database or any other external dependencies of a class your testing, then you would be doing Integration Tests. This is very important also, but first you need to have a good unit test coverage first, then you move level up and start writing higher level integration tests.

Comment: And could you explain why do you use @ Spy and @ InjectMocks annotations? I found some info about them but it's still very unclear.

Comment: Also added edit to my post, I had to change the verify - is that ok?

Comment: I have added the Spy and IncjectMocks info.. Can you add the UserRepository.delete(User) code? with imports please

Comment: Added them in EDIT2. Also I have changed your tests a bit, becasue my findUserByUsername is private so I used findLoggedInUser - provided code for both in edit as well. Could you check if my slightly changed tests are ok?

Comment: I meant the source code of delete method from the UserRepository, not Service

Comment: Added my userRepository.
Also I changed my edits: I am now getting error when doing tests - I changed your code a bit because I found that findUserByUsername method  is useless becasue I have very similiar in my UserRepository so changed my code a bit.

Comment: Ok try this: verify(userRepository, times(0)).delete(any(User.class));

Comment: Unfortunately, still getting an error. Posted Error in EDIT 5.

Comment: In your shouldReturnTrue_whenUserDeleted method you should have verify(userRepository, times(1)).delete(any(User.class);  It should be '1' instead of '0'

Comment: I created three more tests for two methods and I'm not sure if they make any sense. They pass but I don't know if I'm testing the right thing and using verify on right methods. Could you check them for me please? Added them to EDIT 6.

Comment: Especially I don't know what method should I verify in shouldReturnFalse_whenUserNotFoundByUsername because I'm invoking userRepository.findByUsername in my when statement in both tests so is there even a point to verify number of invocations? It's all so confusing to be honest, it just shows that my code sucks becasue it's so had to test, right?