# Spring microservices with OAuth2- ResourceServer returns only String as principal not my custom user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I have two microservices, one is configured as OAuth2 server - A and another one which is configured as OAuth2 client - B. I would like to share my custom user between these two microservices. When the user authenticates himself with the A I create a custom implementation of UserDetails, I would like to protect some resources in B. So that I configured Resource server which is the same as A. I expected that I can share my custom implementation of UserDetails between A and B using Principal. I am able to get the custom user from the principal in A but in B the principal is only represented by String(username). How can I make the resource server to return custom implementation of the UserDetails and not just username?

[source of A - server](https://github.com/pecrom/oauthserver)

Server configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Implementation of UserDetailsService which returns my CustomUser which implements UserDetails(just a dummy one for simplicity)

```
@Service
@Primary
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        GrantedAuthority authority = new Authority("USER");
        return new CustomUser(5L, "username", "{noop}password", Arrays.asList(authority));
    }
}
```

Configuration of OAuth2 server:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                 .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
               .withClient("user")
               .secret("{noop}password")
               .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
               .scopes("webapp");
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

This is how principal "should" be accessible to other services, through rest endpoint which return just Principal, here in service A it contains instance of CustomUser:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserRestController {

    @GetMapping("/auth")
    public Principal getPrincipal(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

Client
[source of B - client](https://github.com/pecrom/oauthclient)

Application.properties - url of endpoint from A

```
server.port=8081
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8080/user/auth
```

Starter of B

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And finally the rest controller which I use to test whether the principal is string(username) or CustomUser. Unfortunatelly Principal always contains just a username and map of fields with values from custom user.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/client")
public class ClientRestController {

    @GetMapping("/print")
    public void printId(Principal principal) {
        System.out.println(principal);
    }
}
```

Could you please help me to solve it? How can I pass Principal with my CustomUser?

Thanks for help:)

Comment: If your Authorization and Resource server are different from one another then this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240197/spring-oauth-with-jwt-custom-userdetails-set-principal-inside-jwtaccesstokenco

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not a good idea to return the Principal object (most probably it will be its implementation class `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`). If you only want an endpoint to share custom user details, then preferable way would be to create a data transfer object that contains only the information that you'd like to expose.

Recommended way to get principal (authenticated user who's making a request) is from security context. More information on this is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37499336/2801909).